# dojox.grid.DataGrid select a row by a column's value

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am not familiar with dojo.  I have this application I am using that has a dojo data grid.

```
    <table jsid="grid" id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="store"
    clientSort="true" style="height: 400px;"  rowsPerPage="10"
    postrender="setTableCount(store,'count');"
    >
<thead>
<tr>
    <th field="enabled" width="24px" styles='text-align: center;'
        celltype="dojox.grid.cells.Bool" formatter="formatterEnabled"
        dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox"><img src='../common/images/check-16.png' title='Enabled'/></th>
    <th field="number" width="100px" >Number</th>

    <th field="name" width="100px" >Name</th>
    <th field="extension" width="100px" >Extension</th>
    <th field="type" width="100px" >Type</th>
    <th field="deleted" width="20px"
        formatter="formatterZombieSkill">
        <img src='../common/images/blocks-delete-16.png' title='Marked for deletion'/></th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

The generated table is large, and I want to highlight 10 rows that are spread out in the grid.  For example, if the extension column is sorted, and it runs from 1..10000, I want to highlight rows 1, 32, 435, and 980.  I can do this with the mouse click while holding down the ctrl button, but when I have 40 values to select, this becomes tedious.

I don't have server-side access to the code, so I just want to simply use my browser's script engine.

I'd like to just type in some quick javascript like:

```
javascript: var x = [1, 2, 3]; for(i in x) { /*SELECT/HIGHLIGHT/SIMULATE-CLICK THE ROW WHERE THE VALUE IN THE COLUMN NAMED EXTENSION = x[i]*/}
```

Can one of you dojo gurus help me out with the missing select statement?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm wondering if the grid holds reference to the rows somewhere in an array that you could query ... I'm not all that familiar with this. If not ... can you include the rows that it generates as well? It looks like you've just pasted the heading above.

Comment: @JasonStoltz - thanks for commenting!  I haven't been checking in lately.  I'll try your suggestion next week - busy weekend:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a dojo guru, but this may do what you need, if you are trying to just programatically select rows... I think DataGrid contains an instance of dojox.grid.Selection.

http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojox.grid.Selection

The Selection dijit has a method called setSelected, which I believe takes an index and a boolean for selected/not selected. So I think you could do:

```
dijit.byId("grid").selection.setSelected(i, true);
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that will do the Select / Highlight that you need. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: I installed firebug in Firefox and realized it was not possible to do this in just the UI, because the grid's contents change as I move the scrollbar thumb.  I'll have to dig into it when I have some idle time.